# shouldComponentUpdate implementation in React PureComponent

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `PureComponent` for better performance in my React application and it has `props` but I don't want it to run render method when this `props` changed. I know we can not use `shouldComponentUpdate` in `React.PureComponent` but my question is:

Is there any way to avoid updating `React.PureComponent`?

I want this component don't update/render at all.

Edit :
I'm getting this warning when using `shouldComponentUpdate` in pureComponent:

> Warning: GameObjectFall has a method called shouldComponentUpdate(). shouldComponentUpdate should not be used when extending React.PureComponent. Please extend React.Component if shouldComponentUpdate is used.

Comment: Use regular `Component` with `shouldComponentUpdate` returns false ? Are you sure you cannot overload `shouldComponentUpdate` from a `PureComponent` ?

Comment: @GabrielBleu i'm getting this warning in edit question when using shouldComponentUpdate in pureComponent.

Comment: Can you post the code of your component (Especially the logic of shouldComponentUpdate method)?

Comment: @SajithDilshan no matter of what logic I'm using in shouldcomponentupdate the warning exist

Comment: The warning is because you have implemented the shouldComponentUpdate method in GameObjectFall component (which is a PureComponent). In-order to get rid of the warning you can extend GameObjectFall from usual react Component and implement shouldComponentUpdate() to return false always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PureComponent` changes the life-cycle method shouldComponentUpdate and adds some logic to automatically check whether a re-render is required for the component. This allows a PureComponent to call method render only if it detects changes in state or props, hence, one can change the state in many components without having to write extra checks.

However you can additionally use the proven method `shouldComponentUpdate` to manually determine the necessity of a new re-render.

<s>It doesn't override the PureComponent logic but adds any other things that you added in the custom implementation of `shouldComponentUpdate`</s>

As of v16.9.0, React throws the following warning

> Warning: shouldComponentUpdate should not be used when extending
>   React.PureComponent. Please extend React.Component if
>   shouldComponentUpdate is used.

See a snippet which illustrates this

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count1: 0,
    count2: 0,
    count3: 0
  }
  
  increment = (key) => {
     this.setState(prevState => ({[key]: prevState[key] + 1}))
  }
  
  render() {
    console.log('render parent');
    return (
      <div>
         {this.state.count1}
         <Child count={this.state.count1} countNew={this.state.count3}/>
         <button onClick={() => this.increment('count1')}>IncrementOne</button>
         <button onClick={() => this.increment('count2')}>IncrementTwo</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
   shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
      console.log('scu');
      if (nextProps.count !== this.props.count) {
        return false;
      }
   }
   render() {
       console.log('render child');
      return (
        <div>Child: {this.props.count}</div>
      )
   }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [PureComponent Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) it only does a shallow comparison in `shouldComponentUpdate()`. Hence, if all your props are wrapped in an object and if you mutate the properties within that object, component will not re-render since shallow comparison will always result in true.

As an example assume `propContainer = {name: "John", age: "20"}` and `this.props.container = propContainer`, then mutation within **propContainer** object (changing name, age values) will not re-render the component.

Answer (score 0):

When using `PureComponent`, there is an implementation to the method `shouldComponentUpdate` which does only a shallow comparison.
You should use it when your props are Boolean, string or any other primitive type.

You can implement your implementation to `shouldComponentUpdate` which will override the default shallow comparison.

When I say shallow comparison I mean that if you were compare between objects/arrays, you would get wrong comparison. For example:

```
const first = { key: 'value' };
const second = { key: 'value' };
if (first === second) {
    // You won't get here
}
```

Comment: so why i'm getting this warning?

Comment: Interesting, I guess it's an new version. Anyway, If you have props that are not primitive types and you want to add conditions to `shouldComponentUpdate`, it's prefer to use the regular Component. @EmadEmami